# What to do when a solution is found on a different website and all given answers are wrong?

Tags: discussion, answers

The most up voted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324235/getting-result-from-query-made-by-php#comment19909667_14324235) is wrong, and I don't want other people to use it. I already commented, but since there are other comments, it's not apparent for someone quickly viewing the answer. Also, I found the correct solution on another forum. How can I accept a right answer when they are not just unhelpful but wrong?

Comment: Why don't you post your own solution and accept that?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, if I could make a suggestion, could you replace the image of your code with the actual code in a formatted block? That would really help if people were to search for this in the future, as well as with visually impaired users or others on slower connections.

Comment: @BradLarson I was trying to but the formatting got royally screwed up. I'll give it another shot and if I can't fix it I'll leave it as plain text, ok?

Comment: @Celeritas - Cool, thanks. I'm surprised that gave you trouble, since I don't see anything out of the ordinary in that code. Sometimes code formatting can be a little finicky, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as posting and accepting your own answer as suggested by [Jack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163745/what-to-do-when-solution-found-on-different-website-and-all-given-answers-are-wr#comment476558_163745), you could comment on and/or down-vote the incorrect answers.

Down-voting is the correct response for something that is incorrect.

One word of warning. Be careful if you decide to down-vote *all* the other answers. This could be seen as suspicious activity by some people.

Comment: even with down voting the vote would be positive and it wouldn't be apparent that the information given is bad

Comment: @Celeritas Which is why I suggested commenting. Also people do expand the vote total to see if there are any down-votes.

Comment: @ChrisF - only if they have enough rep to see both up and downvotes...